# Create function that parses a string into an array PHP

Tags: php, regex, drupal, preg-match

I would like to create a php function that parses a string into an array(which I found not easy), the strings varies alot, I am not sure how to do it in a way that will work properly for any string below($text1,...,$textn):

```
    <?php

    $text1 ='balance_check!en:[ussd]Your balance is $balance $currency;ru:[ussd]Vash balans $balance $currency;';
    //function outputs: $text_array = array ('type'=>'ussd','en'=>'Your balance is', 'ru'=>'Vash balans');

    $text2 = 'voicemail!:[redirect]*44*2*$number';
    //function outputs: $text_array = array('type'=>'redirect');

    $text3='callerid!en:success=[ussd]$callerid is your Caller-ID/error=[ussd]Bad caller-ID number;';
    //function outputs: $text_array = array('type'=>'ussd','en'=>array('success'=>'is your Caller-ID', 'error'=>'Bad caller-ID number'));


    $text4 ='voucher_recharge!en:success=[sms]Your balance is $balance $currency. Voucher recharged successfully';
    //function outputs: $text_array = array('type'=>'sms','en'=>array('success'=>array('Your balance is','Voucher recharged successfully'),),);




//parse into an array
function multiexplode($text) {

        //parse $text into array

        // return  $text_array;
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: what you want is to grab the string and make every word an item of an array?

Comment: Are you building the string as well or do you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: Gerardo, yes. make every word an item

Comment: So the comments under strings aren't how you want the output? Those aren't just "every word as an item".

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, I get the string from SOAP API, the comments under the string is the ouput if I run multiexplode($text1) it should ouput $text1_array

Comment: From what I can see your strings start with substring that tells you the format of the string. You should probably write a function for each format and then use some if statements to filter the strings into the different functions that will return the array formatted properly

Comment: The idea is to make items that users can edit, and then when they save the changes, I should build the string back to API

Comment: Joseph Evans, these are only 4 exemples of how the string may look like, a function that parses these 4 exemples can handle others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure but you can test it :

**EDIT**

```
function transform($string) {
  $string = preg_replace('/\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+/i', '', $string); // remove $words pattern
  $text = end(explode('!',$string,  2)); // get part of string targeted
  preg_match_all('#([a-z]{2})?\:?([a-z]+)?\=?\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]#iU', $text, $matches); // Find all parts needed to build array
  $output = array();
  $text = str_replace($matches[0], '#SPLITME#', $text);

  $sentences = explode( '#SPLITME#', $text);
  foreach ($sentences as $k => $v){
    if(empty($v) || $v == '') unset($sentences[$k]);
  }
  $sentences = array_values($sentences);
  $lang_memory = null;
  foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $lang){
    $output['type'] = $matches[3][0]; // get type 
    if(!empty($lang) ){
      if(isset($matches[2][$key]) && !empty($matches[2][$key])){
        // success or error key found
        $output[$lang][$matches[2][$key]] = $sentences[$key];
        $lang_memory = $lang;
      }else{
        $output[$lang] = $sentences[$key]; // no success of error key found
      }
    }else if($lang_memory != null){
      if(isset($matches[2][$key]) && !empty($matches[2][$key])){
        $output[$lang_memory][$matches[2][$key]] = $sentences[$key];
      }
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for trying. Good start, it is not working for $text1  maybe because there is no 'success' or 'error' in it. so we will need these keys(success and error) only if they are in the original string. Another thing is to remove any word that begins with '$' and remove / (if any).  for example: 
 Array ( [type] => sms [en] => Array ( [success] => Your balance is $balance $currency. Voucher recharged successfully ) )

remove/replace : $balance $currency

Comment: You're welcome , don't forget to validate my answer ;)